# cocos2d deducting objects from array

Tags: xcode, arrays, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

In the following code how could I say have 5 apples in an array, they will fall down one by one with a couple of seconds (or random seconds) between them. Every time an apple falls the array goes 5-1=4 then 4-1=3 etc. and when it reaches 1-1=0 it should stop with dropping apples.

my .h file:

```
@interface xyz : CCLayer {
        CCArray *appleArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCArray *appleArray;
```

my .m file:

```
@synthesize appleArray;

-(id) init
    {
        if( (self=[super init])) {

            // Init CCArray
            self.appleArray = [CCArray arrayWithCapacity:5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                CCSprite *Apple = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Apple4.png"];
                [self addChild:Apple];
                int positionX = arc4random()%450;
                [Apple setPosition:ccp(positionX, 768)];

                // Add CCSprite into CCArray
                [appleArray addObject:Apple];
            }

            [self scheduleUpdate];
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void) update: (ccTime) dt
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            // Retrieve 
            CCSprite *Apple = ((CCSprite *)[appleArray objectAtIndex:i]);

            Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, Apple.position.y -300*dt);
            if (Apple.position.y < -100+64)
            {
                int positionX = arc4random()% 450; //not 1000
                [Apple setPosition:ccp(positionX, 768)];
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to include the QuartzCore framework and link to it.

Add these instance variables in your .h:

```
int _lastSpawn;
double _mediaTime;
int _mediaTimeInt;
int _lastIndex;
BOOL _randomTimeSet;
int _randomTime;
```

In your .m init method add the following line:

```
_mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
_lastSpawn = (int)_mediaTime;
```

Change your update method to this:

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{

    // Get Random Time Interval between 0 and 10 seconds.
    if(!_randomTimeSet) {
        _randomTime = arc4random() % 11;
        _randomTimeSet = YES;
    }

    // Set current time
    _mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    _mediaTimeInt = (int)_mediaTime;

    // Check to see if enough time has lapsed to spawn a new Apple.
    if(_mediaTimeInt < (_lastSpawn + _randomTime)) { return; }

    // Check if first apple has been added or last apple has been added.
    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_lastIndex];
    if(num == nil) {
        _lastIndex = 0;
    } else if(num == [appleArray count]-1) {
        _lastIndex = 0;
    }

    CCSprite *Apple = ((CCSprite *)[appleArray objectAtIndex:_lastIndex]);

    Apple.position = ccp(Apple.position.x, Apple.position.y -300*dt);
    if (Apple.position.y < -100+64)
    {
        int positionX = arc4random()% 450; //not 1000
        [Apple setPosition:ccp(positionX, 768)];
    }
    _lastIndex += 1;
    _randomTimeSet = NO;
    _mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    _lastSpawn = (int)_mediaTime;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Brandon. What I meant was the apples need to fall 1 by 1 after another. Say first apple falls then after 2 seconds next one falls and then after 2 seconds next one etc. It doesnt have to be exactly 2 seconds I could also maybe use arc4random() to randomize the time between them, but I'm not sure how to make the apples fall one after the other. The code I have just drops 5 apples at the same time and same speed. If you could help me out with this it would be great!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I updated my answer. I am not on my dev computer so I could not test this but this should work. Let me know how it goes for you. Keep in mind that if it adds runs through the array prior to the first apple finishing its drop it will then move that one back to the top to start falling again.

Comment: Hello Brandon, thanks for your help really appreciated! It doesnt really work but its getting there I think, I cant seem to find out why it is crashing. It moves the apple a couple of pixels down and then another apple moves down the same way and then it crashes. The Apple falls again from the top because I was testing something with the if statement in the code and I forgot to take it out. Dont need that if statement. Please let me know if it works in your computer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wont be on my dev computer for a few hours but I will check it out when I can. What does the debug window say when it crashes?

Comment: Thanks! This is what it says: terminate called throwing an exception(lldb). When I comment the following code out it drops one apple as it should and thats it. 
    _lastIndex += 1;
    _randomTimeSet = FALSE;
    _mediaTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    _lastSpawn = (int)_mediaTime;

Comment: try changing _randomTimeSet = FALSE; to _randomTimeSet = NO; everywhere that is in the code (I will update it here) and also the places where it says _randomTimeSet = TRUE; change to _randomTimeSet = YES;

Comment: It Does last for a bit longer this time until it crashes.
All the 5 apples move a bit then it stops

Comment: Yes the same thing happens. Before it only moved 2 apples before it crashed but now that you changed false to no and true to yes it moves  all of them one by one then it crashes. I think the rest is alright, there is something wrong with the movement. Maybe because we changed the code totally we need to change the movement code aswell?

Comment: change     } else if(num == [appleArray count]) {
        _lastIndex = 0;
    }

to     } else if(num == [appleArray count]) {
        NSLog(@"Array count: %i", [appleArray count]);
        _lastIndex = 0;
    }

and tell me what the last log prior to the crash says

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'index out of range in objectAtIndex(5), index 5'.  Is this because my array has 5 objects?

Comment: ahh ok that makes more sense now. Change the line (updated in the code above) } else if(num == [appleArray count]) { to } else if(num == [appleArray count]-1) {

Comment: hmm weird, it still does the same thing. Now it gives me this error: Assertion failure in -[CCArray objectAtIndex:]. Im sorry for disturbing you with my questions!

Comment: are you running the code anywhere that removes the child from the array?

Comment: No just double checked now. If you want I can send you the project then you can run it on your computer when you have time.

Comment: sure thing, my email is brandon@brandonlassiter.com

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. I wil tidy it up the code now so you can understand what is going on because it's not the final project it is all messy. I will send you in a bit. This way it is easier for you to understand what I actually mean by apples falling down. Is there any way I can give you a positive feedback or something? im new on this website so dont really know how it works.

Comment: you can either upvote the answer, accept it (although I wouldnt until we have a resolution) or upvote the comments

Comment: I have tried to upvote your answer but it doesn't let me, it says requires 15 reputation to vote. I just sent you the project to your email and I hope it gets solved finally. Thanks, Amin